# "can't find gem" error when trying to create a new rails 5.1.4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

`rails new` works fine. However, when I try to create a new rails project using `rails _5.1.4_ new` I get this error:

```
can't find gem railties (= 5.1.4) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I'm using rbenv on Ubuntu 18.04

I'm running a rails 5.1.4 project on this PC, which works fine, just creating a new one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggested that you don't have Rails 5.1.4 installed in your system. Try install it by `gem install rails -v 5.1.4` and then `rails _5.1.4_ new NewAPP` again.